# Suspend and hibernate stopped working after motherboard upgrade on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, usb, power-management, hibernate, suspend

I recently upgraded my old MSI based Pentium IV motherboard to new Asus M4A79XTD EVO/USB3 and AMD Phenom II X6 1090T with 4 Gb ram. I kept the old HD with Ubuntu 10.10 installed.

After the update I noticed that neither suspend or hibernate doesn't work. Screen goes blank, some lines are displayed and then it returns to login screen.

When checking dmesg I found these two lines which might be the reason for the failure:

```
[26138.433568] pm_op(): usb_dev_suspend+0x0/0x20 returns -2
[26138.433570] PM: Device usb8 failed to suspend: error -2
```

Here's the output of lsusb:

```
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 045e:008c Microsoft Corp. Wireless Intellimouse Explorer 2.0
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 056d:0002 EIZO Corp. HID Monitor Controls
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04cc:1520 Philips Semiconductors 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 152d:2329 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Any ideas how to get suspend work?

Comment: When I replaced my motherboard, Ubuntu had some weird quirks I was never able to resolve. I ended up reinstalling when a new distribution came out and it solved my issues. Perhaps you will need to the that same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, USB3 causes problems and unloading the xhci module helps, more information here:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pm-utils/+bug/562484
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/522998